# When does clang-format break line of the inheritance list?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

Clang-format will always put the inheritance and class name in the same line, regardless of what I set `BreakInheritanceList` to.

I'd like it to format the inheritance list and the constructor initializer list the same way:

```cpp
class Foo
 : Parent
{
  int member;
public:
  Foo
    : member(0)
  { }
};
```

But I can't seem to convince clang-format to change its mind and not produce this:

```cpp
class Foo : Parent
{
  int member;
public:
  Foo
    : member(0)
  { }
};
```

Does clang-format only break the line if it is too long?

Comment: _Does clang-format only break the line if it is too long?_ - Yes, many of `clang-format`s break option applies only if a line break is needed. They have a few options that always applies the break, but these tend to be named `AlwaysBreak...` rather than `Break...`.

Comment: Fair enough, I find it strange that the two are are not consistent then.

Comment: Afaik `BreakInheritanceList` and `BreakConstructorInitializers` are consistent, and should both produce _no break_ in your example above. It may be another option that leads to the break for member initializer list. What `clang-format` version are you using?

Comment: I have no clue which version visual studio 2019 uses, but the extension "ClangFormat" by LLVM which I do use in VS recognizes more options than VS. This extension has number 10.0.0.20191127 in VS, i do not know why the browser listing of it shows 11.0.0.20200203

Comment: I also cannot install the newer version of the extension, I can not update it through VS and I cannot deinstall, then reinstall it to the newer version. Downloading the extension from my brwoser and installing it after deinstall also wont give me the newer version, oh well.